# Extracting long run coefficient in vector error correction model in R

Tags: r, time-series, vector-error-correction-model

I used the `urca` package in R to estimate an error correction model. I used the `ca.jo` and `cajorls` functions for estimation. The results report the coefficients of the model showing bellow:

```
Call:
lm(formula = substitute(form1), data = data.mat)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.24141 -0.07255  0.01178  0.08593  0.23220 

Coefficients:
          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
ect1      -0.28598    0.04589  -6.232 2.91e-08 ***
dem.dl1    0.46455    0.08292   5.603 3.76e-07 ***
compp.dl1 -0.45926    0.19675  -2.334   0.0224 *  
gdp.dl1   -4.30191    4.82234  -0.892   0.3754    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.1202 on 71 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5842,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5608 
F-statistic: 24.94 on 4 and 71 DF,  p-value: 6.43e-13
```

I understand the coefficient associated with the `ect1` is the adjustment coefficient to the long-run equilibrium. However, I have two questions about this estimations.

1. Is there a way to recover the coefficient "inside" the ect1 term, the long-run equilibrium coefficient? Or do I have to estimate it using OLS?
2. Is there a way to calculate the derivative of the dependent variable (`dem`) with respect to the variable `compp`? Or is it just the coefficient for `compp.dl1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding question 1, let the output of `ca.jo` be `x`, then you can get the cointegration vectors as `x@V`. This will contain the coefficients "inside" the `ect1` term.

Regarding question 2, the coefficient on `compp.dl1` will the be effect of lagged (rather than contemporaneous) `compp` on `dem`. Keep in mind that `compp` might be affected by `dem` at the same time as it is affecting `dem` (that is, `compp` might be endogenous w.r.t. `dem`), although it need not necessarily be the case.

See the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf) of package "vars" and/or Pfaff ["Analysis of Integrated and Cointegrated Time Series with R"](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387759661) for more details.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Richard! It's very helpful.

Comment: Regarding the second question, is there a way to derive the marginal effect of contemporaneous terms from the VECM? I know according to the functional form, it seems impossible as all terms are lagged. Or the contemporaneous marginal effect is simply the long-run coefficient? Thanks

Comment: I don't quite know how to do that. It is difficult to define the marginal effect if it is going both ways due to endogeneity. And no, this should not be the same as the long-run coefficient (however you define that).

Comment: Hi Richard. I used the code vecm@V to extract the results. It turns out to be the normalised eigen vectors. Do you know how I can interpret them? I googled it, but it seems there is no good answers out there. Thanks!

Comment: These show the loadings with which the combination of the cointegrated time series is stationary. This combination is the error correction term in the VEC model.